# CakePHP: Showing images in view.ctp

Tags: php, cakephp, view, image

**Goal:**
I am trying to show an image in the view.ctp. I am trying to grab the image that was saved with the rest of the information. I am pretty sure the code is 100% correct in the ProductsController, if not that'll be posted next.

**Here is the code in the view.ctp for products:**

```
<h1>Viewing  Product</h1>

<div><b>Name:</b> <?php echo $Product['Product']['name']; ?></div>

        <div>
            <img src="<?php echo $path .'/'. $row['Product']['filename']; ?> "  width="300px" /> 
        </div>

<div><b>Description:</b> <?php echo $Product['Product']['description']; ?></div>
<div><b>Price:</b> <?php echo $Product['Product']['price']; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read down a bit to see the actual solution.**

Shoudln't

```
        <img src="<?php echo $path .'/'. $row['Product']['filename']; ?> "  width="300px" />
```

be:

```
        <img src="<?php echo $path .'/'. $Product['Product']['filename']; ?> "  width="300px" />
```

?

Since the original poster actually answered their own question I thought I'd elaborate.

**The Solution:**

Replacing:

```
        <img src="<?php echo $path .'/'. $row['Product']['filename']; ?> "  width="300px" />
```

with:

```
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('$Product['Product']['filename']') ?>
```

Comment: And shouldn't it all be replaced with `$this->Html->image(...)`? :)

Comment: http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/products/view/3   That did not work. How would it look with $this->Html->image?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter: I wouldn't know because I don't know anything about CakePHP, but that seems to make more sense.

Comment: <?php echo $this->Html->image ('$Product['Product']['filename']') ?> Yeah I am not very sure where I am getting to